# How to provide theme suggestions based on display mode of media for file video

Tags: theming, media

I want to have a seperate template for Video Media Field to have a play icon on the center of the video. But the file video template doesn't have a suggestion based on Media Video view mode.

[image]

I tried to add it in hook_preprocess_file_video in .theme file, but there is no view mode in the variables. How do we provide a template based on view mode, I saw that there is a way to add suggestions using HOOK_theme_suggestions_file_video_alter, but there also I gont get the display mode?

[image]